# Can't Install WampServer correctly

Tags: wamp

I have downloaded and installed all of the Microsoft VCR's required by WampServer, but I keep getting the error message "The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer."  I click OK and the installation continues.  Once the installation finishes, I try to start wamp server but the icon goes from red to yellow and stays yellow.  Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: install vc_redist.x64.exe ?

Comment: Did you solve this issue: http://i.imgur.com/O52dtTx.jpg @ShoeLace1291

Answer (score 1):

The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer. The problem is that the KB2999226 (Universal CRT) which is part of the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 failed to install. Solution Install Windows Updates: Go to Start - Control Panel - Windows Update Check for updates Install all available updates. After the updates are installed, restart your computer. After the restart repeat the steps above again until no more updates are available.

Download the Visual C++ Redistributable:

For Windows 64-bit http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/3/F/93FCF1E7-E6A4-478B-96E7-D4B285925B00/vc_redist.x64.exe

For Windows 32-bit http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/3/F/93FCF1E7-E6A4-478B-96E7-D4B285925B00/vc_redist.x86.exe

Run the vcredist_x64.exe (64-bit) or vcredist_x86.exe (32-bit) and select Uninstall Run the .exe again and select Install

Comment: I followed your advice but the installer progress bar becomes completely full and then i get Setup Failed with an error saying "One or more issues caused the setup to fail." with the error code 0x80240017

Comment: try to install http://www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0 at C>Windows>System32

Comment: So the exe in the link you provided in your original answer worked after I added the DLL, but now I am getting an error in wamp saying "The procedure entry point ucrtbase.terminate could not be located in the dynamic link library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll."

Comment: can u give a screen shot and where exactly the problem appear it may help

Comment: or why not using xampp ? it's much easier :D !

Comment: It happens right after I choose No in the dialogue asking me if I want to change the default text editor.  Again, installation continues and finishes, but I still can't start wamp. http://i.imgur.com/O52dtTx.jpg

Comment: Sorry I can do nothing else ... but recommending you trying XAMPP

Comment: But what if my PC can't connect to the internet? Is there a way to update manually?

Comment: @Microsmsm Regard your point, https://www.dll-files.com/api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll.html so many files are there, how to choose for my 32-bit os?